# C++ cocos2dx event callback called multiple times

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Yo! I have a small experiment in which I have many touchable blocks. Once touched, blocks must change their properties, like size, color and opacity. But When I touch one block, callbacks assigned to other blocks are also fired. How am I supposed to use Cocos2dx's Event Dispatcher mechanism in order to get only one callback fired (the one, and ONLY one that's assigned to it)? In other words, if I click block A, the onTouchBegin callback assigned to it will be fired. Here's my actual code:

```
bool SimpleGameLayer::init() {

  // ...

  // begin loop here

  auto square = DrawNode::create();
  square->setContentSize( Size(square_size, square_size) );
  // ...
  square->drawSolidPoly(verts, 4, Color4F(0x8b/255.0, 0xb7/255.0, 0xc4/255.0, 1.0f));
  addChild(square, 1);

  // ...

  auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
  listener->setSwallowTouches( true );
  listener->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event) {
            auto target = static_cast<DrawNode*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
            log("TouchBegan on %s", target->getName().c_str());
            return false;
        };

  _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, square);

  // ...

  // end loop here
}
```

No matter what block or square I touch (or click) I always get a bunch of lines:

```
TouchBegan on ....
TouchBegan on ....
TouchBegan on ....
TouchBegan on ....
TouchBegan on ....
```

I also tested my code by adding all the squares with different priorities to no avail.

Comment: What is the value of `square_size`?

Comment: I did not include this part of my code, but it is a positive number, something like `visibleSize.width / float(squares_per_line)` , and squares_per_line is 5, but i dont think this will help solving my issue. Thanks anyways

Comment: onTouchBegan always returns false. So, if the contentSize is like almost the screen size, you'll get TouchBegan events from all nodes.

Comment: Sorry for taking to long to answer. I can't belive I missed that, I thought I was returning true. Ok, my problem is partly solved. Now the callback is called once and for the last DrawNode created even if they have the same priority. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because onTouchBegin allways return false, so it couldn't swallow touch.
if you want only one block get the touch event,you need change you onTouchBegin callback list this.

```
listener->onTouchBegan = [](Touch* touch, Event* event) {
            auto target = static_cast<DrawNode*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
            log("TouchBegan on %s", target->getName().c_str());
            return true;
        };
```